# Buffalo, buffalos and buffaloes

Tags: nouns, american-english

Which plural form of the noun "buffalo" is more common in American English: buffalo, buffalos or buffaloes?

Or would you say they are all equally common and the use of a particular form depends on the speaker's preferences?

Comment: If you go by the [Buffalo sentence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo), it’s *buffalo*.

Comment: I don't know about the US, but in British usage, it is correct to use a 'singular plural' for animals that are hunted for sport or food, e.g. I shot three lion, five partridge, etc. Also two of any killed game bird or fish is called 'a brace'. So three brace of partridge, not 'six partridges'.

Comment: ... but not beef cattle, etc.  *'We dispatched 44 cow and 60 pig at the abattoir today.'

Comment: Thirty brace of wild boar would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These Google ngrams for ten buffalo / ten buffalos / ten buffaloes / a hundred buffalo / a hundred buffalos / a hundred buffaloes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten+buffalo%2Cten+buffalos%2Cten+buffaloes%2Ca+hundred+buffalo%2Ca+hundred+buffalos%2Ca+hundred+buffaloes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cten%20buffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cten%20buffaloes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20buffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20buffaloes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cten%20buffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cten%20buffaloes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20buffalo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20buffaloes%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that the invariant plural far outperforms 'buffaloes' in the popularity stakes, with 'buffalos' very rarely used:

[image]